# Unity3D C#: How to resize an inputfield according the content which is set dynamic

Tags: c#, user-interface, text, unity-game-engine

I've got an InputField where the text is filled in upon getting a string back from the server. We can debug the entire text so we receive it correctly. However the text is too long to fit in our InputField.
What I basicly need is the idea of the content size fitter provided by unity (Content size fitter isn't supported for InputFields by design)
At the moment we are trying to update the size of the InputField with the following snippet of code.

```
var x = new GUIStyle();
var rectTransform = pvText.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
var words = pvText.text.Split(' ');
var currentWidth = 0f;
var currentHeight = 0f;
foreach (var word in words)
{
     var size = x.CalcSize(new GUIContent(word + "A"));
     var height = x.CalcHeight(new GUIContent(word), size.x);
     currentWidth += size.x;
     if (currentWidth >= rectTransform.sizeDelta.x)
     {
        currentWidth = size.x;
        currentHeight += height + pvText.textComponent.lineSpacing;
     }
 }
 rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(rectTransform.sizeDelta.x, currentHeight);
```

Comment: new version of the GUI (i.e. 4.6+) or old version of the GUI?

Comment: The new version unity 4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the font. The font and fontsize is needed to calculate the correct height.

```
var x = new GUIStyle
{
    font = pvText.textComponent.font,
    fontSize = pvText.textComponent.fontSize
};
var rectTransform = pvText.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
var words = pvText.text.Split(' ');
var currentWidth = 0f;
var currentHeight = 0f;
foreach (var word in words)
{
    var size = x.CalcSize(new GUIContent(word + "A"));
    var height = x.CalcHeight(new GUIContent(word), size.x);
    currentWidth += size.x;
    if (currentWidth >= rectTransform.sizeDelta.x)
    {
        currentWidth = size.x;
        currentHeight += height + pvText.textComponent.lineSpacing;
    }
}
rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(rectTransform.sizeDelta.x, currentHeight);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `Content Size Fitter` to your `InputField`, they's PlaceHolder and Text (`all children`)
In `InputField` set `On Change Value` to `ContentSizeFitter.SetLayoutVertical` from yout `Input Field`

Comment: Can you explain what is supposed to happen as I tried to implement and it doesn't change the input field height when the text wraps to a second line.  I have InputField.OnValueChanged mapped to a method that calls ContentSizeFitter.SetLayoutVertical.  But setlayoutvertical doesn't do anything.  Am I missing something more?  What did you mean "they's Placeholder..."?

Comment: 1. Add the `Content Size Fitter` to your InputField
2. Set the `Vertical Fit` to  Preferred Size
3. Set ` On Change Value` to `ContentSizeFitter.SetLayoutVertical()`

Comment: Thank you man so much, I can't even describe how useful this answer is for me.

Answer (score 1):

Or put this UnityScript on the InputField GameObject:

```
#pragma strict

private var inputField : InputField;
private var layoutElement : LayoutElement;


function Awake () {
  inputField = GetComponent.<InputField>();
  layoutElement = GetComponent.<LayoutElement>();
}


// Forces InputField to expand by resizing the background image to the unbounded rect of
// its full text. Remember to set the OnChanged event for the InputField to call this fn.
public function ResizeInput () {
  var fullText = inputField.text;
  var extents : Vector2 = inputField.textComponent.rectTransform.rect.size;
  var settings = inputField.textComponent.GetGenerationSettings(extents);
  settings.generateOutOfBounds = false;
  layoutElement.preferredHeight = new TextGenerator().GetPreferredHeight(fullText, settings);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to Domotor Zsolti: THANK YOU SO MUCH

I have minor alterations that may help someone:
I was trying to make an input field that expands with the text that is being entered.

Hierarchy:Scene>Canvas create UI:InputField
(I deleted Placeholder ChildElement of InputField)
in InputField:InspectorPanel:InputField:Text enter placeholder text (ex:"txt")

Hierarchy view: InpitField:Text childComponent
RectTransform should be set to stretch
 (should already be set by default)
Text childComponent size/corner should be set close to or on InputField corners

InputField: add component: Layout: ContentSizeFitter
ContentSizeFitter: HorizontalFit > PreferredSize
now InputField will shrink to the size of text
placeholder text disapears if its size is set smaller than InputField
- solved by resizing Text component (i spent a lot of time thinking it is an error)

InputField:Inspector:OnValueChanged
drag InputField to Object window
+ select function:ContentSizeFitter:SetLayoutHorizontal

I wanted horizontal expansion, but same can be done with vertical

Again, thank you vety much to Domotor Zsolti, I only figured this out because of his post.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a couple of hours trying for InputField to auto-expand vertically, but even with all hacks it didn't work properly. Turned out that solution is easy - just switch to TMP InputField that works with ContentSizeFitter even without needing to bind OnValueChanged event. Here is a relevant thread on Unity website: https://forum.unity.com/threads/multiline-tmp_inputfield-auto-resize-height-while-editing.641635/